# swift ios: different errors for similar data .. very strange

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Something strange is happening.

I have this in my TableDataArray:

```
(
    {
        count = 0;
        title = Open;
    },
        {
        count = 20;
        title = Closed;
    },
        {
        count = 0;
        title = Pending;
    },
        {
        count = 10;
        title = Queue;
    }
)
```

When I do just:

```
var rowData: NSDictionary = TableDataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary

var maintext: String?  = rowData["title"] as NSString
println(maintext)

if (maintext  != nil ){
    cell.textLabel.text = maintext
}
```

it works, I see the titles in my table.

But as soon as I add these lines:

```
var detailtext: String?  = rowData["count"]  as NSString ## tried also as Int, NSInteger, similar fate

println(detailtext)

if (detailtext != nil)  {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailtext
}
```

The app crashes with "**Swift dynamic cast failed**", and I am unable to figure out why.

Another is if I make another API call, and there, the results are similar, but instead of crashing, it just displays... both the text and detailtext.

Yet in another api call, it crashes, but with '**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**'... and yet in another one, it simply says String is not convertible to Uint8...

And this is bugging me. Same API calls, similar results, but it works in one, and crashes with different results...

So question is, how do I detect and troubleshoot such issues, and then display the detailText... because the values are there.

Thanks.

Comment: Is rowData["count"] holding a NSNumber?

Comment: How you declare your TableDataArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value can't be an `Int` or a `String` because values in `NSDictionary`s have to be objects.  Your `count` is an `NSNumber` which is an object wrapper around a basic number type.

To safely extract the number from your `NSDictionary` use this style:

```
if let count = rowData["count"] as? NSNumber {
    // If I get here, I know count is an NSNumber.  If it were some other type
    // it wouldn't crash, but I wouldn't get to this point.

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = "\(count)"
}
```

This protects you from a whole host of problems.  When you ask for an item from an `NSDictionary`, it is possible the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, and in that case the result will be `nil`.  If you attempt to cast this directly to an expected type, you will get the **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** message.  With the above style, the `nil` is handled gracefully and no error results, you just don't enter the block.

It appears that your `count` can have various types.  You can use a `switch` to handle this in a cleaner way:

```
switch rowData["count"] {
case let count as NSNumber:
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = "\(count)"
case let count as NSString:
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = count
case nil:
    println("value not in dictionary")
default:
    println("I still haven't identified the type")
}
```

Comment: Hi vacawama, Thank you for the answers and i got that my understanding of the NSDictionary is wrong. I was treating it as plain text multi-dimentional array.  Now my app is not crashing, but now, it lists only the Zeros and not the 20 and 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
    if let maintext = rowData["title"] as? NSString {
        println(maintext)
        cell.textLabel.text = maintext

    }

    if var count = rowData["count"] as? NSNumber {
        // If I get here, I know count is an NSNumber.  If it were some other type
        // it wouldn't crash, but I wouldn't get to this point.
        println("\(count)")
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = "\(count)"


    }

    if var count = rowData["count"] as? String {
        // If I get here, I know count is an NSNumber.  If it were some other type
        // it wouldn't crash, but I wouldn't get to this point.
        println(count)
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = count


    }
```

But is this correct way ?